# Distance calculation in metric space

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, gm.general-mathematics

Dear All,

I want to calculate the distance between two sets in which the maximum distance between the sets are minimized. Formally problem defined as,

$\displaystyle \min_{a \in A} \max_{b \in B}$ d(a,b)

This problem looks similar to Hausdorff distance, but the order of $min$ and $max$ are swapped. While a lot of studies can be found about Hausdorff distance, I could not find any study about my problem.

- Is there any specific name of my problem that I missed?
- Do you have any solution advises for the problem except for the complete enumeration? Since the complexity of the complete enumeration is $O(|A| \cdot |B|)$, in my case it is not acceptable as a solution method.

Best Regards

Comment: Gokhan -- this is not a metric. For instance, the distance from $S^1$ to $S^1$ is 2 where $S^1$ is the unit circle in the plane.

Comment: If you want a faster way to calculate the quantity you wrote it might help to say what kind of a metric $d$ is.  Are you working in Euclidean space?  In $\mathbb{R}$ there is certainly a faster algorithm.

Comment: I am working on $R^n$ and distance metric $d$ is $l_1$ or $l_{\infty}$. Thanks for the answers.

Comment: If you're in a low dimensional space, then your problem reduces to performing a set of point location queries in a farthest-point Voronoi diagram under the appropriate metric. 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sort of thing is considered under the name "minimax facility location problem".  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facilities_location.

Comment: This is not quite facility location because you're not "searching" for facilities in the  OP's question - you're given the facilities (the set A)